# How many coin tosses are necessary to have a 50% chance of heads being n wins ahead of tails

Tags: probability

My brother and I were playing a card game (War: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_%28card_game%29).  The game devolved into the question of after how many rounds there is a $50\%$ chance that any of two players has won.  And since we figured we had no chance of solving this problem, we simplified to a sequence of coin tosses.  As stated in the title:

"How many coin tosses are necessary to have a $50\%$ chance of heads being $n$ wins ahead of tails"

For $n = 2$, the problem is trivial, at least for a $50\%$ chance of winning.  There's a $50\%$ chance that a winner appears after two flips.

After $3$ flips:
$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} = 75\%$$ chance of a win having occurred.

After 4 flips:
$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} = 87.5\%$$

It's basically the sequence $\frac{1}{2}^k$, where $k$ is the number of flips.

For $n = 3$, we were unable to find a sequence representing the chance that somebody has won by $k$ flips.

The question is, what is the solution for $n = 3$, and is there a solution for all $n$?

If anybody has a hint, I'd be curious to see how to solve this.

Comment: When $n=2$ there should be a 50% chance of a winner by flip 3 because there are 8 configurations and any of the following are a winner by flip 3: HHH, TTT, HHT, TTH.  Two of those are winners by flip two, so they are winners by flip 3.

Comment: Your title and the first question refer to heads winning, but later it appears you are counting the chance that tails beats heads by at least 2 as well.

Comment: I think this is the symmetric random walk with absorbing walls. I believe the expected time for absorption is $n^2$, although that doesn't differentiate between heads winning by $n$ and tails winning by $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a player (either heads or tails) wins the game when ahead by 2 flips, you are correct that the chance of a winner in two flips is $50\%$.  If nobody has won in two flips they were one heads and one tails, so nobody can win on the third flip.  The chance that somebody wins on the fourth flip is then $\frac 12$ (that nobody won on flip 2) $\frac 12$ (that somebody wins on flip 4)$=\frac 14$  The pattern continues-there is no chance the game terminates on an odd turn an the chance that the game terminates on turn $k$ is $\frac 1{2^{k/2}}$ for even $k$